# Going from a CSV on the local server to populate a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csv

Absolutely brand new to JS. I want to take a csv stored on the localhost and then use the contents to populate a drop down list. I have:

```
    <form id="database" name="database" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label>Customer:</label>
      <select id="custnum" name="custnum">
      </select>
```

I was then going to put the contents of the csv in the drop down using:

```
    <script>
    $.get( "/data/test1.csv", function(CSVdata) {
    data = new Array ($.csv.toArray(CSVdata)); 
    console.log(data)}); ##using this to view if I even had it in the array list
    </script>
```

But this throws: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toArray')

Whenever this was going to start working, I was going to do:

```
var dropdown = $('custnum');
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var record = data[i];
            var entry = $('<option>').attr('value', record.someProperty);
            dropdown.append(entry);
        }
```

Comment: I assume you're trying to use a jquery plugin https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv? Did you load the necessary library script?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation for `$.csv()`. Also note that accessing the file system is a very slow process (relatively) and will likely lead to bottlenecks if this is intended for use in a production system.

Comment: This is where my lack of JS knowledge is an obstacle. I know Jquery-csv is a node.js module. Im making the front end of this site using Python and flask. Can I still get this module?